# OptunaでModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_yaml'

Tags: python, pip, yaml

パラメータ自動最適化ツールの [Optuna](https://optuna.org/) を実行しようとしています。

Optunaをインストールし、Quick Startのサンプルコードを実行しようとしたところ、

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_yaml'
```

というエラーメッセージが表示されてしまいました。

`Lib\site-packages\yaml\cyaml.py`の5行目、

```
from _yaml import CParser, CEmitter
```

で発生します。

Python、optuna、pyyamlのバージョンはそれぞれ以下の通りです。
アドバイス、よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行環境**

```
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)

Name: PyYAML
Version: 3.12
Summary: YAML parser and emitter for Python
Home-page: http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML
Author: Kirill Simonov
Author-email: xi@resolvent.net
License: MIT
Location: c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\chainer5_0_0_py36\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: cliff

Name: optuna
Version: 0.10.0
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: https://optuna.org/
Author: Takuya Akiba
Author-email: akiba@preferred.jp
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\chainer5_0_0_py36\lib\site-packages
Requires: sqlalchemy, numpy, scipy, six, typing, cliff, colorlog, pandas, alembic
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あなたの環境に欠けているものはC言語ベースのyamlライブラリです。
PyPI上のPyYAML 3.12パッケージ（https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/3.12/#files）にこの拡張子があります。

これはおそらくAnacondaを使用することによって引き起こされる問題です。これはPyPIや `pip`ベースのインストールと完全な互換性がないためにしばしば問題を引き起こします。

通常のPythonのインストールを試してみて、Optunaをvirtualenvにインストールしてください。Anacondaは使わないでください。

(Apologies for the use of Google Translate, I studied Japanese for 2 years back in the early 80's but probably cannot even order a beer).

ステップ：
 - 最新の[python 3.6]（https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/）をダウンロードする
-  Pythonをインストールする
- virtualenvを作成する: `\path\to\python.exe -m venv %TEMP%\optuna`
- %TEMP%\optuna\Scripts\activate.bat 
- pip install optuna pyyaml==3.13

(すべてのパスとファイル名が正しいかどうかわからない)

Comment: Anthonさん、回答ありがとうございます。
できれば、作成済のAnacondaの仮想環境にインストールしたいのですが、
リンク先の

PyYAML-3.12-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

をpip installしようしたところ、
cp36でないので、

ERROR: PyYAML-3.12-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

とエラーになってしまいました。

PyYAML 3.13にはcp36があるので、
仮想環境をコピーして、
試しに、そちらをインストールすることを考えています。

試したら、また、連絡します。

Comment: pyyaml3.13を

pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade PyYAML-3.13-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

をインストールしました。
_yamlエラーの代わりに、

Lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py

の43行目で、

NameError: name 'channel' is not defined

のエラーが発生しました。

やはり、Anacondaで環境構築するのは難しいのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトにエラーメッセージが出力されていましたので、そちらも貼り付けます。

ERROR:bokeh.util.dependencies:Failed to import optional module `IPython`
Traceback (most recent call last):
（…）
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\chainer5_0_0_py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 43, in __init__
    val = getattr(stream, meth)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 2585, in name
    return '<' + channel + '>'
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined

Comment: はい、PyYAML 3.13からの3.6インストールが必要です。 元の投稿であるIPythonのエラーが表示されたのではないことを確認してください。 私はまだクリーンな通常のインストールを使用することをお勧めします、私は私の答えにステップを追加します。 それを機能させるようにしてください。これはoptunaのWebサイトに従って機能するはずです。 あなたがアナコンダでこれを持っている必要があるなら、あなたはそれから違いを比較することができます。

Comment: 再コメント、ありがとうございます。
anacondaを使わず、pythonを新規インストールし、py -m venvで仮想環境を構築し、optunaのサンプルコードの実行を確認しました。
アドバイスありがとうございました。
Thanks a lot!

Comment: これであなたの問題は解決したので、答えの隣にあるチェックマーク✓を選択してください。 そのようにして、他の訪問者はコメントを読まなくてもこの問題が解決されることを知っています。